# Can't find tor-resolve on Mac

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, mac, tor-install

Where can I find the `tor-resolve` program to use in the shell on my mac?

I've installed the [tor app](https://www.torproject.org/) from the website it works without any problem.

Now I need to use the `tor-resolve` program that should come with the tor app, but it doesn't seem to be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved by installing `tor` with `homebrew`, by running `homebrew install tor`,  but this doesn't seem to be the way it should be installed since there's an official app and the tor-resolve is supposed to come bundled with it

Comment: The Tor "App" is Tor Browser which is a standalone Browser that works with Tor, `tor-resolve` isn't meant to come bundled with it (likewise other tools like `torsocks` don't come with it either). It's intended to be just a browser.

Comment: Somewhere I read it was supposed to come all bundled, but I guess you're right, maybe on the linux version is different and they were referring to it

Comment: No, tor-resolve isn't provided on any of the Tor Browser distributions. It's provided by the `tor` package but not with Tor Browser.